# Intent provided by Cursor is not fired correctly (LiveFolders)

Tags: android, android-livefolders

In my desperation with trying to get LiveFolders working, I have tried the following in my `LiveFolder` `ContentProvider`:

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { LiveFolders._ID, LiveFolders.NAME, LiveFolders.INTENT } );
    Intent i = null;

    for (int j=0; j < 5; j++) {
        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));
        mc.addRow(new Object[] { j, "hello", i} );
    }

    return mc;
}
```

Which, in all normalness, should launch the Browser and display the Google homepage when clicking on an item in the LiveFolder. But it doesn't. It gives a `Application is not installed on your phone` error. No, I'm not defining a base intent for my LiveFolder.

`logcat` says:

```
I/ActivityManager(   74): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.google.com/ } flg=0x10000000 }
```

It seems it embeds the `Intent` I give it in the `data` section of the actually fired `Intent`. Why is it doing this? I'm really starting to believe it's a platform bug.

---

**Update:** I have filed [an issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7766) and removed the LiveFolders feature. I will include it in my app when I'll get a response either here or there that clarifies this thing. If I get the time I think I'll upload a demo app to that issue.

---

**Update:** I have received a notification that the bounty is expiring in 3 days. No one wants it? :)

---

**Update 04/25/2010:** I have updated [the issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7766) on the Android project and uploaded a test application. It would be nice if someone could test this application on a device, maybe it's such a subtle problem that it only appears on the emulator.

Comment: No, but I haven't tried it with newer versions of Android either.

Comment: I've tried with Android 2.3.3 and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same; and can unfortunately confirm it: The intent is wrapped into the data part of the intent to be fired.

I an wondering if the other predefined CURSOR-columns are evaluated correctly; I thought about filing a bug for the case custom icons (per entry, not one for all of them) are to be returned; but failed. In the whole web I did not find any example or person who were successfull using these columns; only name and id seem to work.

This is one of the main USP features of Android, and it looks like it just failed to be accepted commonly.

Comment: sad.. especially because no one has yet to respond to my issue on the android project..

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue as well.  I think it is because when the Cursor sends it's data to `CursorWindow` in `fillWindow` it can only `putBlob`, `putString`, `putLong`, etc.  I'm not sure how an actual `Bitmap` object (ICON_BITMAP) or Intent object (INTENT) can be passed.  The MatrixCursor will do a `.toString()` on any object.  On an Intent object would be something like: "`Intent { act=android.intent.action.EDIT dat=URI }`".  I don't think the system is correctly interpreting this back to the proper URI.

I've tried serializing the intent into `putBlob`, but Intent isn't serializable. What I have gotten to work is simply passing a URI as the Intent field.  This only gives you the default action on a particular URI, but works.  I'm also having the problem where if I specify "`null`" for the Intent it errors as well, even if I specify a EXTRA_LIVE_FOLDER_BASE_INTENT.  If I don't specify the field at all in the cursor the base intent works, but if I specify the field as null it fails.  It doesn't appear to fall back to the base intent.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try hardcoding component name.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.google.android.browser",
                                   "com.google.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
intent.setComponent(comp);
intent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.BROWSABLE");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
intent.setData(uri);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the same thing happens (application not installed error). In logcat I get: `Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=http://www.google.com/ cmp=com.google.android.browser/.BrowserActivity } flg=0x10000000 }`